# Apache-access logs on Stackdriver

Tags: logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to setup apache-access logs on my Google Cloud VM instance to see all url level traffic coming to the site. I have setup fluentd and gave necessary access control, but I'm unable to see the logs.

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Have you installed the [monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/)? After [installing](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) the monitoring agent, you might need to configure Monitoring to monitor Apache. The [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/apache#configuring) mentioned in the help center article would help you to configure the Apache plugin on your instance. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Stackdriver Logging agent package](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#joint-install) (which is more than just fluentd). The Linux logging agent package pulls in the `google-fluentd-catch-all-config` package, which [configures](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#third-party_application_log_input_configuration) the agent to look for Apache access logs in the following locations:

- `/var/log/apache*/access.log`
- `/var/log/apache*/access_log`
- `/var/log/httpd/access.log`
- `/var/log/httpd/access_log`

On Windows, or if your Linux Apache is configured to log in a different location, the logging agent won't be able to ingest the logs by default — you would have to [configure](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#streaming_logs_from_additional_inputs) it to look in your custom location.

If the logging agent does not report any errors, make sure you are [using the right filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#troubleshoot) in the Logs Viewer.